# Any examples of s3cmd put with --files-from argument

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, s3cmd

I am trying to use `s3cmd put` using the `--files-from` argument as follows:

```
s3cmd --progress put --files-from=list_of_files_to_upload_to_s3.txt s3://softwares/backup/packages/
```

But am getting a `ERROR: Not enough parameters for command 'put'`.

Are there any examples on how to use `s3cmd put` with the `--files-from` argument?

Comment: By the way, these days it is better to use the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) rather than `s3cmd`.

Answer (score 3):

Turns out s3cmd simply (and obviously) needs a source folder in addition to the --files-from argument.

So the final command would be:

s3cmd --progress put --files-from=./list_of_deployit_package_names_to_upload_to_s3.txt SRCFOLDER s3://ewe-softwares/backup/deployit-packages/

Answer (score 0):

With version 2.4.0 on my mac, `s3cmd` insisted that I pass `--recursive`.
Command looks like :

`s3cmd --progress --recursive --files-from=./fichierxlxs.txt put  . s3://mybucket/sousrepertoire/`